# Alter table in mysql

Tags: mysql, performance

I have one existing table with two column ID & Name. This table have around 10 million entry. I want to add one more column in this table of email. This new column will not work as any type of key so this is simple varchar(30). I don't want default value also for this field.

ALTER TABLE `users` 
ADD COLUMN `email` VARCHAR(45);

I want to know how long will it take to alter this table. Will this go and set NULL to all 10 million entry because if it will do so it will take lot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html
Points out that 5.6 can add a column `INPLACE`, but with caveats that probably do not matter in your case.

If you don't have 5.6, then the entire table must be copied over to achieve the `ADD COLUMN`.

Still... The answer to your question depends on the meaning of "faster".  I'll assume it means "minimize how long I cannot write to the table".

Let's look at 3 approaches (pre-5.6):

- `ALTER TABLE` -- cannot write to table until it is finished.  Not fast.
- blue112's approach -- You *can* write to the table, but it won't be copied to the new table.  Still not fast.
- pt-online-schema-change (see Percona.com) -- still slow *but* you can write while it is happening.  It's like blue112's approach with the addition of a `TRIGGER` to keep `users_new` up to date all the time.

Bottom line:  Either 5.6 with `ALGORITHM=INPLACE`, or `pt-online-schema-change`.

Comment: I am using 5.6. 
After reading the reference as i understood if i use Algorithem=inplace it will not assign value to every entry if i don't give any default value and adding column should be fast enough to edit the table again.

Comment: Subsequent editing of the table to actually fill in values -- that will take time.  You would probably do it a little at a time.  One giant update would be perhaps more invasive than a non-INPLACE ALTER.

Comment: Actually i just want to add a column and later as on required will fill the value of the field. So it is perfectly fine for my table to fill the details of newly added column later. This means will my following query work fine.

ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN email VARCHAR(45) ALGORITHM=INPLACE

Answer (score 0):

Is it going to take a lot of time.

You may want to instead do something like that, which is generally faster:

```
CREATE TABLE users_new LIKE users;
ALTER TABLE users_new ADD COLUMN email varchar(45);
INSERT INTO users_new (fields_in_users_table) SELECT * FROM users;
RENAME TABLE users TO users_old, users_new TO users;
DROP TABLE users_old;
```

Comment: How can this be faster. In this case i am actually copying all the data of older user table to newer user table. Which is something like i will read all 10 million records and write them again.